# Как использовать команду " color 3 " в консоли при помощи java?

Tags: java, cmd, командная-строка

Мне хочется чтобы при запуске консольной программы я мог использовать консольные команды.
Проще говоря мне нужно в коде прописать команду (в данном случае "color 3") и после запуска программы эти команды выполнялись в консоли.

В C++ это можно сделать так:

```
system("color 3");
```

А на java фиг знает как :)

Answer (score 2):

В Java для изменения цвета символов (а также цвета фона, стиля шрифта и т.п.) можно использовать [ANSI-последовательности (англ.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), если терминал их поддерживает.

[Пример кода для выбора цвета](https://onlinegdb.com/f90bLz7rV):

```java
public class Main
{
    public static final String ANSI_RESET = "\u001B[0m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLACK = "\u001B[30m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED = "\u001B[31m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN = "\u001B[32m";
    public static final String ANSI_YELLOW = "\u001B[33m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE = "\u001B[34m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE = "\u001B[35m";
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN = "\u001B[36m";
    public static final String ANSI_WHITE = "\u001B[37m";
    
    public static final String ANSI_BLACK_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[40m";
    public static final String ANSI_RED_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[41m";
    public static final String ANSI_GREEN_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[42m";
    public static final String ANSI_YELLOW_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[43m";
    public static final String ANSI_BLUE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[44m";
    public static final String ANSI_PURPLE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[45m";
    public static final String ANSI_CYAN_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[46m";
    public static final String ANSI_WHITE_BACKGROUND = "\u001B[47m";
    
    
    public static void outRed(String msg) {
        out(ANSI_RED, msg);
    }
    
    public static void outGreen(String msg) {
        out(ANSI_GREEN, msg);
    }
    
    public static void outYellow(String msg) {
        out(ANSI_YELLOW, msg);
    }
    
    private static void out(String color, String msg) {
        out(color, "", msg);
    }

    private static void out(String color, String bgColor, String msg) {
        System.out.println(color + bgColor + msg + ANSI_RESET);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        out(ANSI_WHITE, ANSI_RED_BACKGROUND, "  RED  ");
        outYellow(" YELLOW ");
        outGreen (" GREEN  ");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На несовместимом терминале эти последовательности не будут корректно обрабатываться:

- JDoodle
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- [Ideone](https://ideone.com/iVyyu1)
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Другие варианты реализации (через `enum`, с дополнительными кодами для изменения шрифта и т.п.) можно найти по ссылке на основном StackOverflow (англ.): [How to print color in console using `System.out.println`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762491/)

Comment: А другие команды как использовать?

Comment: Какие другие команды?  Есть для них есть соответствующая ANSI-последовательность, то аналогично -- выводится команда для изменения состояния терминала, затем само сообщение.